# R levelplot fill white areas in the maps

Tags: r, levelplot

[image: Map]

Hi, 
I create this nice map with levelplot using the following lines

```
at=seq(min,max,length=n)
colR=colorRampPalette(c("blue","green","yellow", "orange" , "red", "brown", "black" ))                                       
cols=colR(n)                               
res=1e6                                                     
greg=list(ylim=c(-56,84),xlim=c(-180,180))
par(cex.axis=2, cex.lab=2,cex.main=2,cex.sub=2)
print ( levelplot(day001,col.regions=colR(n), scales=list(cex=2) ,cuts=99,at=at,colorkey=list(space="right",adj=2 , labels=list( cex=2.5)), panel=panel.levelplot.raster,margin=T,maxpixels=res,ylab="", xlab=list(paste(des,sep="") , cex=3 , space="left" ) ,useRaster=T) + layer(panel.text(-130 , -50, paste(des,sep="") )   )  )`
```

Min and max are the minimum and maximum of the raster map. Nonetheless, due to the presence of just few pixel in the max i reset manualy to 200. I like the color distribution but i would like to refill all pixel > than 200 ( white part in the Himalaya region) with color black.

Any idea how to set it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but it seems you're asking how to replace all pixels in the `day001` raster with a value larger than 200 with 200.

Assuming `day001` is a `RasterLayer`, just use

```
day001[day001>200] <- 200
```

Comment: Yes, right. I did not think to change the raster value!! Thanks!

Comment: One more question. Why close to the latitude and longitude value a gamma symbol appears? Usually the degree symbol apears but other times gamma show up. Which flag control this? Thanks

Comment: @el_selvaje I can't tell you, I can't reproduce the error. Maybe if you provide a reproducable example. Also, if you think the answer was helpful, could you accept it?